# single view - page - showing data from a group of normalized of tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

What I hope is a basic question,

I am designing an MVC project with the entity framework and code first and in it has a number of normalized tables that later will make up a combined view.

For example say I have a table called JOBS. This table has foreign keys for a CUSTOMER table, a STATUS table, a JOBSTYPE table.

If I want a view (a page) that displays the job with the customer, its status and its jobtype how do I manage this outcome?

In other words if I want a page that shows the job, the customer and the jobs address (sourced from the address table - itself linked via a foreign key in the customer table) how do I do the view for this?

Further, with a focus on CRUD, If I want an update page how do I display a page that has text boxes to update things like the job's address or the status which are in different tables to the actual job table.... and to press a button on the page saying "update" and each table updating automatically..

Look forward to any help clearing the confusion...

Kind Regards
Simon

Comment: Please share a query or some code, anything that you have created or you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as the question, this answer is hypothetical as well. What you can do is have a look at your page design and figure out the columns/properties you want to show from multiple tables, you then create a `ViewModel` for this page, then you can write a [LINQ projection query](https://www.talksharp.com/entity-framework-projection-queries) to bring the results as your `viewmodel`.

Another other option will be to [use lazy loading](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) all linked tables and render related entities, but this this approach you have to make sure that the EF context is not disposed till the whole view has rendered.

The `ViewModel` and `Projection` approach also works well with updates and your update action will take in your view model and translate back to EF entities for updating.

For translations from ViewModel to EF Model entities and vice versa you can use [automapper](http://automapper.org/)

Comment: Yes it was a hypothetical question as I am still trying to pull all the ideas together for best practice... read alot etc. IT seems viewmodels are the way to go. Can I ask a question... a

Comment: It closed the edit....     here is the whole question...  Yes it was a hypothetical question as I am still trying to pull all the ideas together for best practice... read alot etc. IT seems viewmodels are the way to go. Can I ask a question... a viewmodel I believe goes into a viewmodels folder... where do you place the LINQ projecton query.. in the controller.. just before the returning of a view?

Comment: yep the viewmodels goes into the models folder. The linq queries depend upon your architecture, but yep they most likely in your case will go into  the controllers. But if you have a services/repositories architecture then they so in services/repositories

Comment: Appreciated.. slowly building up an understanding.